# Why is clang failing when building wheel for psycopg2?

Tags: django, heroku, pip, psycopg2, heroku-postgres

I know this question or various forms of it has been asked. I am just trying to follow the Django tutorial on Heroku - which involves installing django-heroku, which has psycopg2 as a dependency. I am running MacOS Catalina, 10.15.3.

I know one work around is to download the binary with `pip install psycopg2-binary`, but then I don't know how to get pip to recognize psycopg2-binary and stop trying to install psycopg2 from source when I run `pip install django-heroku`. So I suppose if someone could help me figure out that workaround, that would also suffice - although at this point I think I'm just gonna use Node. In any case, I feel like it's most likely just another instance of Catalina breaking things, but it would be nice to know how to fix this in case I ever have to use django-heroku/psycopg2.

I have upgraded homebrew, reinstalled pyenv/python3.7.4, updated pip. 
I have openssl 1.1.1g installed (homebrew).
I recently reinstalled XCode - but just to be sure it wasn't my compiler's fault, I installed homebrew clang using `brew install llvm`.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/yafeng/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-install-cr8d3luc/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-install-cr8d3luc/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-wheel-wc4izvs3 --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-install-cr8d3luc/psycopg2/
  Complete output (76421 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
...
  194 warnings generated.
  clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/yafeng/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/yafeng/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, psycopg2, django-heroku
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/yafeng/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-install-cr8d3luc/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-install-cr8d3luc/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-record-yhjz7c5j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/8w/_05ytnqn3xlgr133pk_zhzf80000gn/T/pip-install-cr8d3luc/psycopg2/
...
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am running into the same problem.